# Fast way of getting index of match in list

Tags: r, list, optimization, indexing, vectorization

Given a list `a` containing vectors of unequal length and a vector `b` containing some elements from the vectors in `a`, I want to get a vector of equal length to `b` containing the index in `a` where the element in `b` matches (this is a bad explanation I know)...

The following code does the job:

```
a <- list(1:3, 4:5, 6:9)
b <- c(2, 3, 5, 8)

sapply(b, function(x, list) which(unlist(lapply(list, function(y, z) z %in% y, z=x))), list=a)
[1] 1 1 2 3
```

Replacing the `sapply` with a for loop achieves the same of course

The problem is that this code will be used with list and vectors with a length above 1000. On a real life set the function takes around 15 seconds (both the for loop and the `sapply`).

Does anyone have an idea how to speed this up, safe for a parallel approach? I have failed to see a vectorized approach (and I cannot program in C, though that would probably be the fastest).

**Edit:**

Will just emphasize Aaron's elegant solution using match() which gave a speed increase in the order of 1667 times (from 15 to 0.009)

I expanded a bit on it to allow multiple matches (the return is then a list)

```
a <- list(1:3, 3:5, 3:7)
b <- c(3, 5)
g <- rep(seq_along(a), sapply(a, length))
sapply(b, function(x) g[which(unlist(a) %in% x)])
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3
```

The runtime for this was 0.169 which is arguably quite slower, but on the other hand more flexible

Comment: What do you want the algorithm to do if an element of `b` appears in more than one element of `a`?  Is that possible in your actual problem?

Comment: I should have specified that... It is not a possibility

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's one possibility using `match`:

```r
a <- list(1:3, 4:5, 6:9)
b <- c(2, 3, 5, 8)
g <- rep(seq_along(a), sapply(a, length))
g[match(b, unlist(a))]
#> [1] 1 1 2 3
```

`findInterval` is another option:

```r
findInterval(match(b, unlist(a)), cumsum(c(0, sapply(a, length))) + 1)
#> [1] 1 1 2 3
```

For returning a list, try this:

```r
a <- list(1:3, 4:5, 5:9)
b <- c(2, 3, 5, 8, 5)
g <- rep(seq_along(a), sapply(a, length))
aa <- unlist(a)
au <- unique(aa)
af <- factor(aa, levels = au)
gg <- split(g, af)
gg[match(b, au)]
```

Comment: From 15 sec to 0.009 - thats an impressive improvement. I found out that I would actually like to return a list instead of a vector, so that it can handle multiple matches. I substituted the last line in your first suggestion with sapply(b, function(x) g[which(unlist(a) %in% x)]) to achieve this. The run time was then 0.169, which is quite slower than your but still a major improvement.

Comment: For future reference: using the first option (`match()` with `seq_along()`) is exactly as fast as the second option (`match()` with `findInterval()`) in R 4.2. Both versions work already in R 3.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment to your post suggests, it depends on what you want to do if/when the same element appears in multiple vectors in `a`. Assuming that you want the lowest index you could do:

```
apply(sapply(a, function(vec) {b %in% vec}), 1, which.max)
```