# How do you determine which element in a list contains a value matching some other value?

Tags: r, list, match

If I have the following list:

```
a <- list(1:3, 4:5, 6:9)

a
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 6 7 8 9
```

I want to determine which element of the list a specific value is in. For example, I might want to find which element the number 5 falls under. In this case it would be `[[2]]`.

My goal is to have something like

```
match(5,a)
```

return the value `2`.

However, this code only checks whether the selected number exists as a complete element of a given element

```
match(5,a)
[1] NA
```

Further, unlist only tells me where in the entire length of all values my number of interest falls:

```
match(5,unlist(a))
[1] 5
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Also, what is the proper lingo when talking about the elements/parts of a list in R?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast way of getting index of match in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002391/fast-way-of-getting-index-of-match-in-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` function

```
grep(5, a)
# [1] 2

grep(9, a)
# [1] 3
```

## Updated Answer

After reading @nicola 's comment came to know that `grep` command works only for the numbers that belong to start and end of the list and not for the numbers that are in between.

You can try the below mentioned code for the complete solution,

```
a <- list(1:3, 4:5, 6:9)
df <- data.frame(unlist(a))
df$group <- 0
k <- 1
i<-0
for(i in 1:length(a)) 
{ 
 x[i] <- length(unlist(a[i]))
 for(j in 1:x[i])
 {
  df$group[k] <- i
  k <- k+1
  }
}
colnames(df)[1] <- "num"
df[df$num == 5, ]$group

# [1] 2
> df[df$num == 9, ]$group
#[1] 3
df[df$num == 8, ]$group
# [1] 3
```

Comment: This won't always work. `grep(2, a)` gives `integer(0)`.

Comment: thanks @nicola for mentioning that. I didn't notice. I have updated the answer.