# Conditionally assign column value based on partial match to at least 1 element in vector

Tags: regex, r, apply, sqldf

I have 2 data frames

```
market<-c('New York, NY','Some place in Chicago','Lala land')
d1<-as.data.frame(market)
metro<-c('Chicago','Meow','New York')
d2<-as.data.frame(metro)
```

I need to create another column `d2$inmarket` that is 1 when the `d2$metro` area can be found in `d1$market`, else 0. My goal is for d2 to look like this:

```
     metro inmarket
1  Chicago        1
2     Meow        0
3 New York        1
```

I have explored `grep` and `sqldf` options, but nothing I have seen answers my question.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002391/fast-way-of-getting-index-of-match-in-list) would return index of `d1` where there is a match, but I would need index of `d2` in order to assign value 1 or 0.

I can also use `sqldf` to select the rows in `d1` where there is a match, but I can't go the other way around, because I can't search `d2$metro` for `d1$market`, obviously.

```
d1$market<-as.character(d1$market)
d2$metro<-as.character(d2$metro)
find<-function(x){fn$sqldf("select market from d1 where market like '%$x%'")}
p<-d2$metro
m<-lapply(p,function(y) find(y))
data.frame(matrix(unlist(m)))
    1 Some place in Chicago
    2 New York, NY
```

Any ideas?

edit: this works for one element, but I need to loop:

```
d2$inmarket[grepl('Chicago', d1$market)] <- 1
```

Comment: Could try something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(d2)[, inmarket := +any(grepl(metro, d1$market, fixed = TRUE)), by = metro]` maybe.

Comment: You can try `+(d2$metro %in% gsub(paste0('.*(', paste(d2$metro, collapse='|'), ').*'), '\\1', d1$market))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg What is `fixed = TRUE` for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to substring 'market' column in 'd1' and use `%in%`

```
d2$inmarket <- +(d2$metro %in% gsub(paste0('.*(', paste(d2$metro, 
        collapse='|'), ').*'), '\\1', d1$market))
d2
#     metro inmarket
#1  Chicago        1
#2     Meow        0
#3 New York        1
```

Comment: This is a nice one, but it could get messed up if `df$metro` is a big vector as `gsub`/`grep*` functions have a limit for their pattern argument size.

Comment: @DavidArenburg You are right.  Another option is `library(stringi);sapply(d2[,1], function(x) any(stri_detect_fixed(d1[,1],x)))`